# Assigning a reserved IP to a VM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-vm-role

I am trying to assign a reserved ip address to a newly created VM on Azure. I am following steps indicated here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

Here is what I am doing and the error it throws:

```
## Create VM Config with a cloned VHD (no issues here)
$migratedVM = New-AzureVMConfig -Name 'IP-CLONE' -DiskName 'TEST-AgendaCondivisa-2014-05-28.vhd' -InstanceSize 'Small' 

## Reserve an IP address 
$ReservedIP = New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "IP-CLONE" -Label "IP-CLONE" -Location "Japan West" 

##Create VM
New-AzureVM -ServiceName "IP-CLONE" -Location "West Europe" -VMs $migratedVM -ReservedIPName $ReservedIP 

OperationDescription                                                       OperationId                                                                OperationStatus                                                           
--------------------                                                       -----------                                                                ---------------                                                           
New-AzureVM                                                                933fe90c-e087-bc26-882d-f5c79148f23e                                       Succeeded                                                                 
New-AzureVM : BadRequest: The Reserved IP **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.ReservedIPContext does not exist.**
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureVM -ServiceName "IP-CLONE" -Location "West Europe" -VMs $migratedVM -Re ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.PersistentVMs.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Needless to say, if I do not use the “-reservedipname” switch everything works fine and the VM gets created without throwing errors.

Any idea?

Comment: What's the output of `Get-AzureReservedIP $ReservedIP`? Maybe `$ReservedIP` is invalid or null..

Comment: It throws the same error:
Get-AzureReservedIP : ResourceNotFound: The Reserved IP Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.ReservedIPContext does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureReservedIP $ReservedIP
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureReservedIP], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.GetAzureReservedIPCmdlet

Comment: Try `New-AzureReservedIP` with different locations and/or labels/names, it might be one of the switches that's tripping you up.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me on the right way. Actually is not a problem of location or labels name, but on variable content.

The correct way to store data in variable is:
-ReservedIPName $ReservedIP.ReservedIPName
$ReservedIP = Get-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "IP-CLONE"

Than you can you call the switch this way:
-ReservedIPName $ReservedIP.ReservedIPName

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reserving an IP address in "Japan West" and trying to assign it to a new Azure VM to be created in "West Europe"

You must reserve an IP address from the same region you want to deploy your VM to

Reserve an IP address in "West Europe" or create your VM in "Japan West"